# Properly Matching a IDN URL

Tags: php, regex, url, dns, idn

**I need help building a regular expression that can properly match an URL inside free text.**

- **scheme**

  - One of the following: **ftp**, **http**, **https** (is **ftps** a protocol?)
- optional **user** (and optional **pass**)
- **host** (with support for IDNs)

  - support for **www** and **sub-domain(s)** (with support for IDNs)
  - basic filtering of TLDs (`[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` is enough I think)
- optional **port** number
- **path** (optional, with support for Unicode chars)
- **query** (optional, with support for Unicode chars)
- **fragment** (optional, with support for Unicode chars)

Here is what I could find out about sub-domains:

> A "subdomain" expresses relative
>   dependence, not absolute dependence:
>   for example, wikipedia.org comprises a
>   subdomain of the org domain, and
>   en.wikipedia.org comprises a subdomain
>   of the domain wikipedia.org. In
>   theory, this subdivision can go down
>   to 127 levels deep, and each DNS label
>   can contain up to 63 characters, as
>   long as the whole domain name does not
>   exceed a total length of 255
>   characters.

Regarding the domain name itself I couldn't find any reliable source but I think the regular expression **for non-IDNs** (I'm not sure how to write a IDN compatible version) is something like:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\-]{2,62}
```

**Can someone help me out with this regular expression or point me to a good direction?**

Comment: With "support for IDNs", do you mean that it should support www.emilvikström.se or just the punycode version www.xn--emilvikstrm-0fb.se ?

Comment: @Emil: emilvikström.se, I believe I should have to use the `\p{L}` property but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Gruber, of Daring Fireball fame, had [a post recently](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) that detailed his quest for a good URL-recognizing regex string.  What he came up with was this:

`\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))`

Which apparently does OK with Unicode-containing URLs, as well.  You'd need to do the slight modification to it to get the rest of what you're looking for -- the scheme, username, password, etc.  Alan Storm [wrote a piece explaining Gruber's regex pattern](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained), which I definitely needed (regex is so write-once-have-no-clue-how-to-read-ever-again!).

Comment: This is probably good if you add the username and password part ( protocol://username:password@subdomain.domain.tld/path?querystring#anchor )

Comment: I tested this pattern att it works to get the whole URL. Maybe it's easiest to just run the found URLs through parse_url () afterwards.

Comment: @delfuego: How does that regex differ from this one `(?:[\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s<>]+(?:[^[:punct:]\s]|/)`?

Comment: Alix, look at the linked Alan Storm piece in my comment for an explanation of each part of John Gruber's regex string, and then you'll see what's missing from yours.

Comment: @Emil: "This function `parse_url` is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts". And the `filter` extension fails to validate IDN URLs.

Comment: @Alix, that's correct.  So in this case, the regex handles finding valid URLs, and then the `parse_url` function breaks the now-validated URLs into their component parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you require the protocol and aren't worried too much about false positives, by far the easiest thing to do is match all non-whitespace characters around `://`

Comment: to eliminate the false ones, run the results through `filter_var` and if that doesnt return false, run it through `parse_url` to get the components.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you most of the way there.  If you need it more refined please provide test data.

```
(ftp|https?)://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

Comment: Is that a valid URL? from http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt ... only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

Comment: See RFC3490 about internationalized domain names. In technical terms like DNS it is always converted to punycode, but it is shown in applications with the international characters.