# non-latin email address validation

Tags: php, validation, email, icann

Now that ICann is allowing non-latin-character domain names, should I be concerned about e-mail validation?  Currently, my sites are using php functions to ensure some alpha-numeric character set in each segment of an email address.  Will these other character sets, such as Cyrillic, Arabic, and Chinese, pass validation?  Are there recommended php functions to utilize for this?

Comment: @John Conde: you've already typed it up, please post it so we can upvote something other than your comment.

Comment: Well, it's not much of a solution but at least it explains where PHP currently stands with this. Hopefully the Questioner chooses some solutions for their previous questions. There are some good answers in them.

Comment: Why not just send an email and have the user confirm the address by clicking a link? You'll save yourself some big headache. 

There isn't any safe method to guarantee that the user is giving you a proper address. Even if it is syntactically correct, one can always use Mailinator or similar services to provide a valid (but useless for you) email address. So, why bother checking?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ultimately best way would be using a proper IDN function to convert the incoming string into an ACE string (`xn--xyz-blah.com`). If that process works, the domain name is valid. If it doesn't, it isn't.

There is a PHP function named [`idn_to_ascii()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php) that does this, but it needs additional libraries. You'd have to see whether it is available on your system.

There also seems to be an external Linux command named `idn` that does IDN conversions. I don't know anything further about it, though.

If you want to use PHP built-in methods only, delfuego provides a regular expression in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974941/properly-matching-a-idn-url) that looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to recommend using [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter. But after a Google search it turns out it [doesn't support multi-byte characters](http://community.impresscms.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=35127) yet. It looks like, for now, your best bet is to [strip out non-latin characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php) and perform the usual validations against that (although [checkdnsrr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) will obviously fail since you've changed the domain by removing the non-Latin characters and replaced them with their Latin equivalents so if you use that to verify the MX records of the email's domain then you will need to temporarily disable that).

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL also appears to be excessively strict even when dealing with non multi-byte characters.

Comment: Filter  FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL supports FILTER_FLAG_EMAIL_UNICODE flag as of PHP 7.1.
Please note, that it only allows for unicode characters in the local part of the email address, as stated in the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php#constant.filter-flag-email-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

It is not ICANN allowing non-latin email addresses, but the arrival of new norms, coming from IETF standards body and its "EAI" working group.

So, yes, technically, today, `café@café.été` is a valid email address: non ASCII left part, non ASCII domain, non ASCII TLD.

But, a lot of existing, or even new codes, will fail to accept those cases. Of course it is a chicken and egg problem because people wanting to use that and seeing refusal by many sites will go back to ASCII which will show little appetence for non ASCII and hence little evolution.

There is an ICANN initiative about all of that called "Universal Acceptance" which concerns itself not just with IDNs but even with new gTLDs, as there are still places hardcoding TLDs and hence not reacting to new TLDs that were opened few years back, or with silly regular expression such as a TLD must be 2 or 3 characters long, which is wrong.

You can find it at: https://uasg.tech/

It as advices and links for various kind of public, starting with developers, and hence list of things to do/not do.

They recently published a new article, that show trends over 3 years about the highest visited sites based on Alexa and which kind of email addresses they allow or not: https://www.circleid.com/posts/20210712-acceptance-of-all-domain-names-in-open-source-software/

With the report at https://uasg.tech/wp-content/uploads/documents/UASG033-en-digital.pdf going into more details about Java and Python libraries and their handling of IDNs.