# php filter_var unicode domains

Tags: php, regex, filter-var, punycode

I am writing validation form, and using standart php function "filter_var" with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, but it seems that above mentioned function does not work with unicode domains such as .рф, after reading some articles tried to encode with punycode and filter but no success. 
I just was curious is there any universal way to validate email not using regexp
Thanx in advance

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899236/non-latin-email-address-validation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219848/how-to-validate-non-english-utf-8-encoded-email-address-in-javascript-and-php

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev, the links you provided answered my question

Comment: @Kamil fun fact: you were already using regex since the filter you used does use a regex under the hood :)