# How do I match japanese characters using IDN regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, idn

Based on this post [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974941/properly-matching-a-idn-url)

i came up with a regex for javascript

```
\b(([\w-]+:\/\/?|[\w\d]+[.])?[^\s()<>]+[.](?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]|\/)))
```

this one matches urls like

- `http://google.com`
- `http://www.google.com`
- `google.com`

It fails for `google`, but when I used japanese characters like `功功.jp` it fails.

- `www.功功.jp`
- `http://www.功功.jp`
- `http://功功.jp`

These match. What should I change so that `功功.jp` also matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very slight modification made here has it working for me:

```
/(([\w-]+:\/\/?|[\w\d]+[.])?[^\s()<>]+[.](?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]|\/)+))/
```